# Why can get_key() be used even if it is not called explicitly?

Tags: python, typing

I am coding a poker game along with a github file. This is the part of the code. As you can see, I have the get_key()function which I think is supposed to return the keys of the selected card. But in the second to last line of code "player.arrange(get_key)", it does not call the function. But the the code still works perfectly, so I wonder why is that? What is passed into the arrange method in class Player? Thank you.

```
class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self._cards_on_hands = []

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    @property
    def cards_on_hands(self):
        return self._cards_on_hands

    def get(self, card):
        self._cards_on_hands.append(card)

    def arrange(self, card_key):
        self._cards_on_hands.sort(key=card_key)


    def get_key(card):
        return (card.suite, card.face)
    def main():
    p = Poker()
    p.shuffle()
    players = [Player('Eva'), Player('Dude'), Player('Peta'), Player('Bruh')]
    for _ in range(13):
        for player in players:
            player.get(p.next)

    for player in players:
        print(player.name + ' : ', end=' ')
        player.arrange(get_key)
        print(player.cards_on_hands)
```

Comment: Can you see that `get_key` is being passed (as `card_key`) as the `key` parameter to the `sort()` call? You should investigate the `sort()` method of `list`.

Answer (score 0):

`get_key` is a function. Not the result of a function call but function. In your case this function is used to sort cards. `key` parameter of function sort accepts functions so that is why this code works fine.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions

Answer (score 0):

you are passing `get_key` instead of `get_key()`:

`player.arrange(get_key)` instead of `player.arrange(get_key(your_card_parameter))`

This then gets passed to `sort(key=card_key)` which also accepts functions as keys. I wouldn't say it works. This is a bug waiting to happen.

---

The takeaway from this is you can pass functions as arguments!

You would be able to avoid this if you used type hints (if you are using Python >= 3.5 [no reason not to]).

For example:

```
from typing import Tuple
card_key_t: type = Tuple[int, int] # I don't know what it should really be as you did not show `card.suite` and `card.face`.

def get_key(card) -> card_key_t:
    return (card.suite, card.face)

def arrange(self, card_key: card_key_t):
    self._cards_on_hands.sort(key=card_key)
```

Pycharm would show a warning if you passed a `Callable` (a function) instead of an `int`.

---

Response to comment:

> I am a bit confused because even in the arrange function I did not see
> card_key() being explicitly called

@AD11011 `player.arrange(get_key)` passes the function itself to `arrange`. In `arrange` it is called `card_key`:  `self._cards_on_hands.sort(key=card_key)` which then gets passed to the built in `list.sort`: `sort(key=card_key)`. So we see that list's `sort` gets called with `key=get_key`.

See [list.sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) documentation:

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
> comparison key from each list element

It gets called inside `sort`.

It is hard to know what exactly happens there without knowing what is `(card.suite, card.face)`

Comment: So the get_key() function is passed into the arrange function, and then is called with arrange function by player?  Is the process: get _key() get the values from player, then the values are sorted?

Comment: I am a bit confused because even in the arrange function I did not see card_key() being explicitly called